# access runtime backend enryption error

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Relatively new to access. I have a split database for access where the back end database is encrypted. It works fine. However, when I try it in a run-time environment I get the error `"Execution of this application has stopped due to a run-time error. The application can't continue and will be shut down"` on loading the database. 
When I remove back end encryption it works fine with run-time.

I don't know where to start looking to correct this error.

Comment: Do you have a form autoloading on startup?  If so, make sure you're doing error trapping (On Error GoTo MyError:) and then pop up a custom messagebox with the error number and error description.  It may give you something more specific to look into.

Comment: You probably have an AutoExec macro that runs on startup? If so, begin stripping commands from that macro until the error goes away.